# spinner onItemSelected making issue

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have made 2 spinners and my 2nd spinner is dependent on the 1st one. When I click on the 2nd spinner my program get crashed. This is what my logcat says:

```
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:332)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:328)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-11 12:09:35.076: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
```

And here is my code:

```
package com.test;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{

     boolean flag=true;
     Spinner spinner;
     public String [] doctorsname=new String[1000];

    String[] items = {"psychologist", "neurologist","dentist"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.searchact);

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
         doctorsname[i]=null;

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,DocprofileextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);       
        }
    });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,DocprofileextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);       
        }
    });
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
    {

         if(parent==spinner)
         {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, items[position], 2000);
            toast.show();

            logintosever obj1=new logintosever();

            try 
            {
                doctorsname=obj1.searchbycategory(items[position]);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                flag=false;
            }

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.doctorsname);

            if(doctorsname!=null)
            {
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,doctorsname);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setEnabled(true);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {
                spinner.setEnabled(false);
            }
         }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {

    }


    public void onItemSelected2(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: your namingconventions is so ugly,,,,Both spinner name are same and where you put listner for secon spinner?

Comment: thnx for your response samir, ok i will change the names, moreover i have saw the tutorial in which the person had made 2 spinners but have 1 listener and in which he is identifying it by "this" same as i have done for spinner1

Comment: you are passing null array to array adapter. please only post code where you feel error can occur. so it will be more readable as well as track-able.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting my comments to you first because they seem more important:

- Please go back to your old questions and accept answers - [how does accepting an answer works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) - it also explain why you should..
- Please next time you post your code try to remove irrelevant code it will stack your chances to make people read through your code.

about your question i'm not really sure but its a NullPointerException that means you are trying to use a variable with a null value in a place that doesn't accept null
maybe try to change your toast variable to this-

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "item:"+items[position], 2000);
```

so you cant put null inside your toast..

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is your array size is mismatch with you adapter suppose , your array is of 10 element and your adapter will have only 5 element from it ,

means 
string [10] ={"a","b","c","d","e"};